# Testing for html lang attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lang

I'm using the following code to check for the `lang` attribute on the `<html>` element:

```
if( $("html:lang(en)") ){
  // Do something
}
```

I've noticed that this doesn't work consistently. For instance, when `lang="fr"`, or when no language attribute is defined, the code still gets executed.

According to the jquery docs (https://api.jquery.com/lang-selector/), it should work. How come this isn't the case? And most importantly: How do I check which `lang` attribute is used in a consistent manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$("html:lang(en)")` would be always a [truthy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) since it returns a jQuery object. Instead, you need to check [length property](https://api.jquery.com/length/) of returned object to check the element existence.

```
if($("html:lang(en)").length){
  //          here --^^^^^^^^--
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `[]` selector and check the `length` property to know if it exists:

```
if ($("html[lang='en-us']").length) {
    //do something.
}
```